# How can I boot my other OS automatically when I reboot?

Tags: reboot

I have both Linux and Windows installed on my computer.

I want to set it up so that that every time I reboot my computer it automatically loads the other OS:

```
  Linux-> (restart) --> Windows
Windows-> (restart) --> Linux
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @AndroidDev - not true, you use grub-reboot NUM where NUM is the number of the grub entry to boot. See https://wiki.debian.org/GrubReboot

Comment: You would have to ask on a windows forums for how to tell windows which os to boot.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - I think it would be impossible to tell Windows what to boot, since Windows can't read EXT4 to modify the config file

Comment: Thanks for your answers! So, the closest solution for me is always boot my computer with ubuntu by default and from there run 'sudo grub-reboot <num>' when I want to change of OS

Comment: @AndroidDev - You would have to ask on a windows forums.